# What are the ways to test a php site's performance for load?

Tags: php

Is it possible to test a php site's performance for hundred thousands  of users before it actually achieves that user base?

What are the tools? Can it really be realistically judged based on these tools?

Comment: You _can_ test it like that, but it will never be reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xl-t's suggestion of apache bench (ab) is good for quickly pounding on a script or two.  That's a good place to start.

There's also [siege](http://www.joedog.org/index/siege-home), which is a little more sophisticated.

If you want to get fancy, and have easily repeatable tests, you should have a look at [jmeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/).  The learning curve is a little steep at first, but it can model/simulate a huge number of scenarios.  It's got a GUI, but the GUI be configured to run the tests from a remote box.  Ideally, you'd use a server that's close to your web app's server.

Running any tests from your local machine is likely to benchmark your network connection rather than your application.

Answer (score 5):

You don't say much about your server setup. How many servers? What OS? Which databases?

Well, for a start, you might want to try „ab“, the Apache HTTP server benchmarking tool.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html

You can simulate any number of concurent requests. Best thing would be to write a test suite that simulates a number of typical user activities: sign-up, sign-in, post something, download some file and the like. Then you can run this test suite from a number of clients at the same time and simulate some hundred or thousand users simultaneously.

Then take a look at your server system and see how it performs. Log data to find bottlenecks and improve your system iteratively.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [Seige](http://www.joedog.org/index/siege-home)

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5171727.html